# Read on closed stream error from apache HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient, inputstream, apache-commons-httpclient, apache-abdera

I am trying to parse a response from the Apache HttpClient (3.1) response like this:

```
try {  
    int code = mclient.executeMethod(method);
    if (code == Status.OK.getCode()) {
        st = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
        XMLBean el = doSomething(st);
        return el;
    }
} catch (HttpException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    method.releaseConnection();
}
```

This is giving me the following exception while parsing the response with atom parser.

```
org.apache.abdera.parser.ParseException: java.lang.RuntimeException: [was class java.io.IOException] Attempted read on closed stream.
```

The finally block actually closed the connection. What might causing this closed stream error?

```
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.apache.abdera.parser.ParseException: java.lang.RuntimeException: [was class java.io.IOException] Attempted read on closed stream.
    at org.apache.abdera.parser.stax.FOMBuilder.next(FOMBuilder.java:244)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMElementImpl.java:337)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMChildrenQNameIterator.next(OMChildrenQNameIterator.java:118)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getFirstChildWithName(OMElementImpl.java:275)
    at org.apache.abdera.parser.stax.FOMElement.getFirstChild(FOMElement.java:180)
```

Comment: Impossible to tell from what you've given us. What does `doSomething` do?  Which line was the exception thrown on?

Comment: doSomething(in) basically parse the InputStream using Abdera:     Parser parser = Abdera.getInstance().getParser();
Document<Element> doc = parser.parse(pInputStream);

Comment: Got the same problem - did you find a solution?